# argparse - asks for argument that's already been given

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

i'm trying to run my file with the following command:

```
python3 file.py -p pony_counts num_words
```

where my argparse code is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('pony_counts', type=str, help="output file for compute_pony_lang.py")    
parser.add_argument('num_words', type=int, help="num of words we want in the output list for each speaker")
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.pony_counts) as f:
    df = json.load(f)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df) # convert json to df
df = df.drop([i for i in df.index if i.isalpha() == False]) # drop words that contain apostrophe

total_words_per_pony = df.sum(axis=0) # find total no. of words per pony
df.insert(6, "word_sum", df.sum(axis=1)) # word_sum = total occurrences of a word (e.g. said by all ponies), in the 7th column of df
tf = df.loc[:,"twilight":"fluttershy"].div(total_words_per_pony.iloc[0:6]) # word x (said by pony y) / word x (total occurrences)
    
ponies_tfidf = tfidf(df, tf)  
ponies_alt_tfidf = tfidf(df, tf)      

d = {}
ponies = ['twilight', 'applejack', 'rarity', 'pinky', 'rainbow', 'fluttershy']

if args.p:
   for i in ponies:
       d[i] = ponies_alt_tfidf[i].nlargest(args.num_words).to_dict()
else: # calculate tfidf according to the method presented in class 
   for i in ponies:
       d[i] = ponies_tfidf[i].nlargest(args.num_words).to_dict()

final = {}
for pony, word_count in d.items():
    final[pony] = list(word_count.keys())  

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent = 2)
pp.pprint(final)
```

my code runs with the command - however, the else block runs regardless of whether the command contains the -p argument or not. would really appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: '-p`' gets the 'pony_counts' string.  'num_words' is then given to 'pony_counts', leaving nothing for 'num_words'.    Put '-p' last if you don't want it to grab the following string.

Comment: A `nargs='?'` optional is most useful when you also provide `default` and `const` parameters.

Comment: That `-p` doesn't make sense. Why is it `type=str`? Why `nargs='?'`? Why is the long name `--optional` instead of something that matches its description better? What does it even mean? It sounds like it's supposed to just be a flag, not something that takes a parameter.

Comment: We don't have enough information about what this was *supposed* to do to tell you how to do it.

Comment: What kind of value is `-p` supposed to get?  As defined it will be either `None` (default) or the string provided by the user.

Comment: -p is an optional argument that, when passed, should call a different method. my command now runs, but -p is running the wrong code block. i'll update my code + description.

Comment: With those changes I don't think we can help anymore.  I would recommend adding a `print(args)`, to verify that the parsers has done what you want.  Then in the `if args.p` block(s), and another print or 2 to confirm which block is executed.  Judging that based just on `d` values requires a lot more knowledge what the calculations are supposed to do.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, my bad - didn't realise until i fixed the problem. turns out i forgot to assign my df to a new variable, so args.p and no args.p were supposed to be printing the same stuff anyway. i use argparse quite frequently though, so this will advice come in handy. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the command:

```sh
python3 file.py -p 10
```

is equivalent to:

```sh
python3 file.py -p=10
```

In Bash (assuming you're on a Mac or Linux) the whitespace is treated the same as an equal sign after a flag. So if you wanted to pass a value for the `-p` flag you would need to structure it more like:

```sh
python3 file.py -p <tfidf arg> <pony_counts> <num_words>
```

Just reading your code, perhaps you want `-p` to be a true / false flag instead of an input? If so you can use `action='store_true'` or `action='store_false'`. It's pointed out how to do this [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action). Ripping an example out of the documentation:

```py
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
>>> parser.add_argument('--baz', action='store_false')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo --bar'.split())
Namespace(foo=True, bar=False, baz=True)
```

Comment: The whitespace/`=` equivalence isn't something that Bash does. That equivalence only holds if the program receiving the arguments actually treats both versions as equivalent. In this case, it's something `argparse` handles.

Comment: Apologies. You're right. Yes the equivalence depends on the application handling the input but that typically holds true for a lot of modern CLIs.